# Cross platform framework for thin-client to a .net backend?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cordova, xamarin.ios, multiplatform

A system is to have an ASP.Net MVC back-end. Part of the UI will be simple HTML5 + JavaScript.

There is another part that will be a thin client. The goal is to have it natively implemented for the several most popular consumer platforms - Windows, OSX, iOS, Android and possibly WP7. (and why not Windows 8 Metro App?)

What is the best choice of development tool to use for this purpose?

The two that come in mind are:

1. Mono + MonoTouch + MonoDroid. Code in C#, user interface in... what?
2. HTML5/JS + PhoneGap. A concern will be how can this behave as a native app on Windows and OS X.

Am I missing a good alternative? Am I missing some caveats and hidden traps?

What would be the most 'future-proof' framework? Are there any examples of other people doing this very concrete scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a lot of questions and I won't try to answer all of them. There are already several similar (and good) questions and answers on the those subjects here in stackoverflow. I suggest you to look at the most popular questions in each **tag** and you're likely to find opinions (best choice), alternatives, caveats...

Here's one (less recent): [Targeting/Developing for multiple mobile platforms with one programming language (C#)? Cost-Benefit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335764/targeting-developing-for-multiple-mobile-platforms-with-one-programming-language)

Now specifically about:

> Mono + MonoTouch + MonoDroid. Code in C#, user interface in... what?

With that approach you can get the real *native* UI on each platform and user experience on each of them. This might look like a lot of work (and it could be depending on your application) but it does not have to be (again a lot of code can be shared, same MVC pattern). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936066/mono-for-ios-android-open-or-closed-paid-or-free/7936176#7936176) from a customer case.

**Disclaimer:** I work for Xamarin (maker of both MonoTouch and Mono for Android)

Answer (score 1):

I think if you are looking at the part of what system  best fit.  I would go with a latest release of MVC4 since it has an option to create a views that will be specifically used for the mobile devices which uses java-script to perfectly render components but it would be a web app that would look and feel like a mobile app. Choosing between mono and phone gap I would probably go with monotouch since it has a lot more features and it would probably be easier to implement it in you app.

Comment: MVC4 does not really help with the thin-client-ness at all. And using Mono I will really need to support at lest 4 distinct platforms (Win + OS X + Andrid + iOS).