# is monocross free?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, monocross

I want to develop with monocross android apps, but I read somewhere that it is not really free.
Can you develop for android with monocross for free, or u need to pay for some kind of extension (like monodroid). How does it work?

If it isn't free, are there any other alternatives? I don't mind paying for something that will help me code faster, but certainly not 1000$ per year.

Comment: Where did you read that it's not really free?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
(Xamarin.Android || Xamarin.iOS) != monocross
```

MonoCross is a framework that works on top of Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS to leverage the Model View Controller (MVC) pattern. MonoCross itself is not paid for, but if you want to use Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.iOS with more than 32KB of compiled code you will need to pay for a license for the products.

That being said, MonoCross is nice, but it seems that further development has been stopped and nothing new has happened to the framework for a long long time. Another nice framework called MvvmCross which is similar to MonoCross is also out there. The differences are that MvvmCross as it name suggests it uses the ModelView View Model (MVVM) pattern instead of MVC. It is also under rapid development and has an active community. Just like MonoCross it is free.

**Both MonoCross and MvvmCross needs Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.iOS if you want to develop for the two mobile platforms.**

However Xamarin.Android is not the only C# for Android project out there. There is also a project called [dot42](http://www.dot42.com/), however it is not as popular as the Xamarin products and not backed by a company with lots of resources. Hence your mileage may vary.

Comment: great answer, I haven’t yet enough rep to up it, but I am sure others will do :).
thanks

Comment: Agreed; great answer!  very complete and accurate.

Answer (score 3):

Yes' it's free. It's released under [the MIT Open Source License](http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php) to which there is a link at the bottom of the [Monocross home page](http://monocross.net/).

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
>   without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
>   the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
>   EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
>   MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
>   IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY
>   CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
>   TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
>   SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

Comment: thanks Matthew for the quick response, but do you know if I can develop android apps using it and without needing to purchase something else, like monodroid?

Comment: Hmm well I think Mono for Android isn't free. Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936066/mono-for-ios-android-open-or-closed-paid-or-free

Comment: I wonder why someone just downvoted this answer... Monocross is definitely free (http://monocross.net/about)... *Monocross is released under the MIT license, which means that anyone is free to download, contribute and share the framework.*

Answer (score 2):

Monocross development has not been halted.  It is still under active development, the team that released the Monocross cross-platform framework has been hard at work on [iFactr](http://ifactr.com), their enterprise level UI abstraction layer with data cache and queue.

They just announced a recommitment to the open source community on Xamarin's cross-platform forums.